# Share list of objects between Web and Desktop app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I would like to share the list of objects     `List<MyObject>` between web and desktop app.
I have ASP.NET MVC app which will put new object to that list and desktop app which will read these object, modify them and put back to list and then ASP.NET MVC will pick up changed objects. Shortly speaking queue of objects. 
What is the easiest and fastest method to share such list between apps? I do not want to use Windows Communication Foundation or other large frameworks, do not want to add another layer which will bring complexity.

Comment: http://juristr.com/blog/2011/08/posting-json-data-to-aspnet-mvc-3-web/

Comment: You can use database to store these objects.

Comment: What do you need to do to this list that ASP.NET MVC will not do?

Comment: The ASP.NET MVC will accept jobs and will put them to queue list. This queue will be used to perform jobs which is memory and time expensive. I do not want to create worker threads in Web app.

Comment: @sgud Database is not fast enough and I do not want to add another layer to this solution. Web and Desktop app will be on the same PC and I am sure there is better solution to share object.

Comment: @Tomas Serilization FTW! If you are new to it check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since the only way you can share data between two different apps (in two different machines I'm assuming) is to serialize the data then send it, then using a remoting library like WCF is your only recourse. You can also use XML Web Services (asmx files), which are a lot simpler than WCF.

If the two apps share the same machine, that opens up a few more opportunities. Mainly using a shared resource between the two. Here are a couple of ideas:

- Serialize the list into an XML file and save it in a shared location, and have both apps access it. You'll need to take into account synchronization and that sort of thing (both apps trying to access the file).
- Use a database to store the list and have both apps connect to it.

Any more details would depend on the nature of the apps and the data, but I think that's a good starting point.

Comment: The apps will be used on the same machine and this brings more options I think.

Comment: @Tomas - Edited answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

asmx webservice is the best method ,you just you call the web service in your destop app like

using youapp.yourwebservice;

after that you can use any of the object web service easily ,when you will call the webservice it will create a reference .cs file automatically ,which will have the class and its methods.